# Medialets to track iPhone app usage etc

Tags: iphone, analytics

Has anyone used medialets to track iPhone app usage ? Their documentation leaves a lot to be desired..

Comment: I have used their library and had no issues following the step-by-step instructions in the PDF that accompanies it. If you can add some more specifics or details to your question I might be able to better assist you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be too difficult to set up and use the basic features.

Simply include the library in your project and ensure that your target links against it.
Then add an entry to your target's info.plist with the key:

```
MMAppID
```

The value should be your Medialytics appID.

After thats set up, you should be able to start the tracking from within your AppDelegate's initialize method:

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    [[MMTrackingMgr sharedInstance] startDefaultTrackingWithoutLocation];
}
```

That will give you the barebones tracking for your app.

As for custom events, I haven't looked into that.

Comment: Thanks... I will try this right away ( despite the fact that it is still before sunrise here ! )

Comment: @Jasarien: When I used their sample app, I see nothing in the Xcode console. It is just blank. I 'm trying to see what "tracking a basic event" does. I did insert my appid into the info.plist file ( I did not know this until I saw your post )

Comment: @Jasarien: Silly question... how do I make sure that I am linking to  the library. I dragged the "libMMTracking.a" file to my projects..and it shows up under frameworks.
I also had to include the "MMTrackingMgr.h" file.
Now I get a bunch of link errors when I build..

_compress referenced from 
-[MMBroadcaster compressURLRequestForEvents:datalsMIME64:]....

Comment: Make sure that the libMMTracking.a is included in the Link Binary With Libraries build phase in your project's target.
Alternatively, you add it to the "Other linker flags" in your build settings using the flag -lMMTracking (omit the 'lib' portion of the library name).

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. I had to clear some entries in my LIB_SEARCH_PATH. 
Compiles and links fine now.

I also turned on logging. I see some messages flow thru. All looks fine.

However, now I do not see any usage under my app in the medialets analystics web site.
http://www.medialytics.com/app_reports/runs

I've emailed their developer support web site. I double checked my MMID.. it is correct.

....log snip...
[Session started at 2009-10-21 15:22:55 -0400.]
2009-10-21 15:22:57.609 InternationalNews[5300:207] *MMT* starting tracking (2.0 build 37) with location  (run ID 0)
2009-10-21 15:22:57.615 InternationalNews[5300:207] *MMT* tracked event => [3:277845777:0] 2009-10-21 15:22:57 -0400: "MMRunStartEvent" (NotConnected)  (run ID 108F9711)
2009-10-21 15:22:57.616 InternationalNews[5300:207] *MMT* finished tracking with location start-up  (run ID 108F9711)
2009-10-21 15:22:57.616 InternationalNews[5300:207] *MMT* tracked event => [3:277845777:0] 2009-10-21 15:22:57 -0400: "TEST RUN" (NotConnected)  (run ID 108F9711)
2009-10-21 15:22:57.623 InternationalNews[5300:207] *MMT* start handling app notification: UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification  (run ID 108F9711)
2009-10-21 15:22:57.626 InternationalNews[5300:207] *MMT* tracked event => [3:277845777:0] 2009-10-21 15:22:57 -0400: "UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification" (NotConnected)  (run ID 108F9711)
2009-10-21 15:22:57.629 InternationalNews[5300:207] *MMT* finish handling app notification: UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification  (run ID 108F9711)
2009-10-21 15:23:00.616 InternationalNews[5300:207] *MMT* got new location: <+37.33168900, -122.03073100> +/- 100.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2009-10-21 15:23:00 -0400  (run ID 108F9711)
2009-10-21 15:23:07.617 InternationalNews[5300:207] *MMT* max queued event age reached - attempting broadcast  (run ID 108F9711)
2009-10-21 15:23:07.867 InternationalNews[5300:207] *MMT* successfully sent events to server  (run ID 108F9711)
-- end log snip .--